# What options are there to setup automatic reporting processes for Pandas on AWS?

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm currently using elastic beanstalk and apscheduler to run Pandas reports everyday automatically on it. The data set is getting larger and i've already increased the memory size 3x.

Elastic Beanstalk is running Dash - dashboard application and runs the automated Pandas reports once every night.

I've tried setting up AWS Lambda to run Pandas reports on there but I couldn't figure out how to use it.

I'm looking for the most cost-effective way to run my reports without having to increase memory usage on Beanstalk. When I run it locally it takes 1gb but running it on beanstalk, it's using more than 16gb.

Curious if someone else has a better option or process how they automatically run their Pandas reports.

Comment: Why you couldn't make it work on lambda? This might be the way to go?

Comment: The database is in another AWS login so I got stuck at permissions errors trying to accessing it while running the report.

Answer (score 0):

Create an .exe using Pyinstaller
Schedule .exe on Task Scheduler on computer

Cheaper than scaling AWS Beanstalk resources which use more resources calculating pandas than your computer locally at least for my case.